# Is locking a mutex for a long time safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, thread-synchronization

There is a set of problems in which mutexes themselves (without additional stuff like condition variables) can be used to synchronize threads.

For example, let's say I want a background thread to perform some possibly-time-consuming initialization and then to perform its main job, but the main job should start not earlier than I give a signal from the main thread:

```
std::thread backgroundThread ([]() {
    initialize ();
    waitForSignalQ ();
    doMainJob ();
});

…;

emitSignalQ ();
```

Yes, I know that I can use mutex + boolean variable + condition variable to implement `waitForSignalQ` and `emitSignalQ`. Or, I can use void-returning future + void-returning promice for the same purpose, as Scott Meyers suggests.

But the simpler approach here seems to be using just a single mutex:

```
std::mutex myMutex;
std::unique_lock <std::mutex> backgroundThreadCantStartItsMainJob (myMutex);

std::thread backgroundThread ([&myMutex]() {
    initialize ();

    // This line won't return until myMutex is unlocked:
    std::lock_quard <std::mutex> (myMutex);

    doMainJob ();
});

…;

// This line will unlock myMutex:
backgroundThreadCantStartItsMainJob.unlock();
```

But is this approach valid? Or are there some drawbacks (for example: OS-level mutex-locking time limit, false positives from software analysis tools, etc)?

<sub>P. S.:

• Yes, I know that the problems will arise if `myMutex` isn't unlocked (due to an exception before `backgroundThreadCantStartItsMainJob.unlock()` or etc), but the question is not about that (with condvar and future approaches we get the same problem if the main thread "forgets" to emit the signal Q).

• Yes, I know that in practice it might make sense to have several variants of signal Q (like "proceed to the main job" vs. "cancel"), the question is not about that (as well as the condvar and future approaches, the discussed approach allows passing extra data too).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific downsides to locking a mutex for a long time.

If I understood correctly, you have a thread that will lock a mutex during its init. Another thread will try to get that mutex (to be sure the init of the other thread is finished) and then get the mutex for the rest of the program runtime.

That is fine. There's no runtime cost with having the mutex. The OS will not time it out or anything. The challenge is a software engineering one: Make it clear, readable and understandable for the person that will have to maintain it. Apart from that, the architecture is really up to you.

Comment: There is one down-side: Mutexes are not _intended_ for signalling between threads. They are only intended to provide mutual exclusion. There are numerous other patterns—semaphores, blocking queues, etc.—that can be used for signalling. The down-side is, even if you can make it work, you are doing something _unconventional_. That means extra work for other programmers who may be called upon to read and understand your code. That means, other programmers (maybe your team-mates in a large organization) will be less happy to work with you, answer your questions, fix your bugs, etc.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, do you consider such mutex-only synchronization to be harder to read/understand than the one based on mutex+condvar+bool?

Comment: @Sasha, If I needed to create a thread that would wait for a signal before proceeding, then my first thought would be to use a semaphore. I always prefer to use standard library classes when they are available, so probably, `std::binary_semaphore`. 
 Perhaps that class would be implemented by "mutex+condvar+bool," but those are low-level details. They would be of interest to somebody who wants to understand how the semaphore works, but not useful for the person who wants to understand how _my_ code works.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, and if using C++20 isn't an option, what you would do then?

Comment: Depends on project requirements.  Maybe [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores), or maybe create my own `class Semaphore`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, ok, thanks. For me all that seems to be overcomplication. For me simpler code is easier to read. But I appreciate your opinion too.